# How can I sniff packet with Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, packet-sniffers

I have already installed Wireshark in my laptop. Is it posssible to sniff the packets that my mobile phone sends through the internet? e.g. I open the browser in my mobile phone and I hit a simple link www.bbc.com , how can I sniff the packets that are transferred. They both to have connected to the same network?Because my mobile phone phone is connected to a network SSID1 and my laptop to SSID2.
Because I lack of experience in using wireshark if it possible suggest a link , so to make a quick progress and be more familiar with this software.
Thanks a lot

Comment: As long as you can run Wireshark on a network node (=PC) that both of these network cross, you can have these two devices connected to two different wifi networks. Otherwise, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if you can capture network packets on another network, then no that's impossible. You'd need to be on the same network as the device.

Thinking about it like catching fish in a river. If you cast a net in one river to catch all the fish swimming by you'll be successful. If you cast a net in this same river to catch fish in a river next to this one, you're going to be unsuccessful.

For an overview of the different modes you can use wireshark on the same network, look [here](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).